# How to fetch record to sum upto a value and then add into two new tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to sum (add the values) from the database. My application checks the values from each row, adds up the value from each row up to 2000. And once it reaches up to 2000, it saves in the database (insert query) and continues the same till last record fetched. The total value summed (or totaled) up by each rows should not exceed over 2000.

There are two insert queries, One for inserting the total( from each row between 1800 and 2000) with the ID (like Primary key) generated and the second table add each row inserted with ID (the ID generated becomes now foreign key)

Please refer to the screenshot.

[image]
Please find the code below:

```
$i = 1;
do {                
    $id = $row_FetchRecordRS['ID'];
    $dateissued = $row_FetchRecordRS['DateIssued'];
    $rundateCarrierRun = $row_FetchRecordRS['RundateCarrierRunID'];
    $timegenerated = $row_FetchRecordRS['TimeGenerated'];
    $carrierID = $row_FetchRecordRS['CarrierRunID'] ;
    $areaID = $row_FetchRecordRS['CarrierAreaID'];
    $address = $row_FetchRecordRS['DeliveryAddress'];
    $potzone = $row_FetchRecordRS['Postzone'];
    $carr_ID = $row_FetchRecordRS['CarrierID'];
    $instruction = $row_FetchRecordRS['DeliveryAddress'];
    $areaRep =  $row_FetchRecordRS['AreaRepDetails'];
    // $vendor = $row_FetchRecordRS['VendorDetails'];
    $quantity = $row_FetchRecordRS['Quantity'];
    $direct = $row_FetchRecordRS['Direct'];
    $jobID = $row_FetchRecordRS['JobID'];
    $jobName = $row_FetchRecordRS['JobName'];
    $bundlesize = $row_FetchRecordRS['Bundlesize'];
    $bundle = $row_FetchRecordRS['Bundles'];
    $items = $row_FetchRecordRS['Items'];
    $weight = $row_FetchRecordRS['WeightKgs'];
    $totalWeightCol = $row_FetchRecordRS['TotalWeightKgs'];
    $date = date("D M d, Y G:i");

    $total_weight =  $row_FetchRecordRS['FinalWeight'] + $total_weight ;
    echo "Row: " .$row_FetchRecordRS['FinalWeight']. "<br>";
    echo "Total is______  $i : $total_weight <br><br>";  

    $sqlquerytest = "INSERT INTO `GenerateRun`
        (`DateIssued`, `RundateCarrierRunID`, `TimeGenerated`, 
        `CarrierRunID`, `CarrierAreaID`, `DeliveryAddress`, `Postzone`, 
        `CarrierID`, `DeliveryInstruction`, `AreaRepDetails`,  
        `Quantity`, `Direct`, `JobID`, `JobName`, `Bundlesize`,   
        `Bundles`, `Items`, `WeightKgs`, `TotalWeightKgs`,   
        `LodingZoneID`) 
        VALUES 
        ('$dateissued', '$rundateCarrierRun', '$timegenerated',  
         '$carrierID', '$areaID', '$address', '$potzone', '$carr_ID',  
         '$instruction', '$areaRep', '$quantity', '$direct', '$jobID',  
         '$jobName', '$bundlesize', '$bundle', '$items', '$weight',   
        '$totalWeightCol','$i')";

    mysql_select_db($database_callmtlc_SalmatDB, $callmtlc_SalmatDB);
    $ResultUpd1 = mysql_query($sqlquerytest, $callmtlc_SalmatDB) or die(mysql_error()); 

    if ($total_weight >= 1800) {            
        $sqltransitlist = " INSERT INTO `TransitList`(`genID`, `total`) Values ('$i','$total_weight')";
        mysql_select_db($database_callmtlc_SalmatDB, $callmtlc_SalmatDB);
        $ResultUpd3 = mysql_query($sqltransitlist, $callmtlc_SalmatDB) or die(mysql_error());

        $i = $i+1;
        $total_weight = 0;          
    }
} while($row_FetchRecordRS = mysql_fetch_assoc($FetchRecordRS));
```

Comment: I don't completely follow your code, but I would suggest that you try to see if you can do the summing inside MySQL and not in PHP.

Comment: I tried the calculation inside the sql, but cant fetch the records and i guess i was getting some errors

Comment: Since this may primarily actually be a SQL question, you might want to show sample input data and the expected output.

Comment: $row_FetchRecordRS['FinalWeight'] .  Where is this coming from?

Comment: $row_FetchRecordRS['FinalWeight'] is coming from the table column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your line of codes are irrelevant to your problem. I will simplify it for you.

```
$i = 1;
$total = 0;
$arr = array(); // for storing a list of data provides that the total doesn't exceed 2000
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($record)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $num = $row['num'];
    $arr[] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'num' => $num);
    if ($num + $total > 2000) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(genID, total) Values ('$i','$total')";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        foreach ($arr as $data) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Table2(ID, name, genID, total) Values ('$data[id]','$data[name]','$i','$data[num]')";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        }
        $arr = array(); // empty the array as the data has been stored to database
        $i++;
        $total = 0;   
    } else { // if the total doesn't exceed 2000, add it to total
        $total += $num;
    }
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(genID, total) Values ('$i','$total')";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
foreach ($arr as $data) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Table2(ID, name, genID, total) Values ('$data[id]','$data[name]','$i','$data[num]')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Note: this code is just a sample, not your actual code. You can implement my code and match it to your code.

Comment: thanks david. I was just wondering, where does your $total defined? or its just at the start $total = 0; ?

Comment: Hey david, how are we calculating the $total in the first insert sql?

Comment: you can check it in else part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176686/discussion-between-sarah-malik-and-david).

Comment: Please consider whether you really want to be advocating archaic, insecure, and deprecated code on this site.

Comment: the OP use `mysql`. I am just following OP. No need to be hostile.